# Set C dependency locations when installing R packages

Tags: r, r-package

How do I specify the location of header files which are a dependency for an R package?

Concretely:

```
install.packages('tiff')
```

dies with the following message:

```
common.h:5:18: fatal error: tiff.h: No such file or directory
```

However, when I do the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='~/tiff-4.0.3/libtiff'
```

and then repeat the installation procedure, it again dies with the same message.

```
Sys.getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

shows

> ~/tiff-4.0.3/libtiff

Manytnx!

Comment: I don't have sudo, and cant' install libtiff-devel using yum.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used for run-time linking. You are looking for ways to change the compile-time include and library paths. Many R packages have a `configure` script where such things can be adjusted. I am not sure about `tiff`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many packages use `configure` scripts to find external dependencies or let the user specify their location. That is not the case for the [`tiff`](https://github.com/s-u/tiff) package. You have to modify the package in order to install it. Untested:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/s-u/tiff
$ cat > tiff/src/Makevars <<EOF
PKG_LIBS=-L<directory-containing-tiff-library> -ltiff -ljpeg
PKG_CFLAGS=-I<directory-containing-tiff-header>
EOF
$ R CMD build tiff
$ R CMD check tiff_*tar.gz
$ R CMD INSTALL tiff_*tar.gz
```

You will still need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to get the run-time linking correct.